# Windows 10 ownership issues with storage drive

Tags: windows, permissions

Windows 10 seems to have ownership of my storage drive as someone other than me. I have tried to set owner by going into properties, security, advanced and changing the owner but it still doesn't let me copy files to that drive.

[image]

I just tried to copy some photos from my phone and it pops up an error titled 'Error Copying File or Folder' and then says 'Access is denied.' I copied the same photos to a location on my OS drive and it worked fine.
All I want is it to treat every folder in every location the same as C drive; I am the owner and only user of the PC, I just want full access!

I apologize if this has been asked elsewhere but trying to find a proper solution among the other non-helpful info seems impossible..

Comment: Can you post screen shot of Advanced Security Settings for other drivers.

Comment: What do you mean doe other drivers?

Comment: The advanced security settings look like http://i.imgur.com/uWeYVVo.png

Comment: Have you tried enabling "Replace all child object permission ..."?